# bootstrap button's proper dropdown alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to remove two issues with the dropdown button.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgj248ew/3/)

1) If you press the button and hold is shows a some kind of shadow (button pressed style) around the name "Button name 1 or 2"

2) The second problem is with the dropdown menu of "Button name 2". If I change the button's name to "Button Name 22222" the dropdown menu doesn't move to right, but it stays at the same place, it should auto align from right as the arrow points.

I don't know how to fix these two things. Please help.

**HTML:**

```
 <header class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red">
          <div id="topbar1">
            <div class="dropdown right">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Button Name 1 <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu Item 2</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red">
          <div id="topbar2">
            <div class="dropdown right">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Button Name 2 <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu Item 2</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#topbar1 .btn, #topbar2 .btn {
  border: none;
  background:none;
}

#topbar2 {
  width: 130px
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.dropdown-menu {text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; min-width: 130px}

.col-sm-3 {
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue "shadow" is an outline, you can set it off by using `outline: none`.

The dropdown right alignement was broke because of the width of the parent element.

I removed the `width: 130px;` rule, and to keep your button aligned to the left i added .pull-left to your button, and added .clearfix class to its parent, to not break the dropdown position. The `outline: none` rule is under `#topbar1 .btn, #topbar2 .btn {}`.

Here is the fiddle fixing the issue :

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martinlemahieu/fgj248ew/4/)

I hope this helps ! :)

EDIT :

I moved up the .pull-left and .clearfix classes in this fiddle, to have a perfectly right aligned dropdown, because the .pull-left directly on the button was breaking the alignement.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martinlemahieu/fgj248ew/5/)

EDIT 2 :

I totaly removed any shadow on the buttons, by adding `box-shadow: none;` ;)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martinlemahieu/fgj248ew/6/)

Comment: thank you. The alignment works fine now!! There is still problem with the "shadow" I don't see the difference. You can still notice something when pressing the button, it should be fully transparent not matter if I press or not.

Comment: this isn't actually a shadow I'm using wrong vocabulary, I don't how to call it but it's some kind of border around with the shadow. Maybe if you remove the red border then it will be more clear to see.

Comment: I updated the answer, adding a new fiddle where I remove the shadow "inside" the button, I hope this is what you were trying to do. :)